# Comparing position with Prev/next position in array

Tags: java

PROBLEM SOLVED! Thanks

This is my first question in this forum. I did not get what's the problem here.

JAVA8: I am trying to compare if the object in position X in an array of a string is the same than other in position x-1 or x+1 (at least one).
This condition has to be solved for all the positions in the array. For example, We are given AABCBC as an input, it has to be false because BCB is not satisfying our conditions, but as output, it shows ok.

```
//b is String[] of chars --> F.E.:["B","B","A","B"]
int len= b.length;           
boolean l_r=true;
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
            boolean left=false;
            boolean right=false;

            if(i+1<len ){ if (b[i].equals(b[i+1])){ right=true;}}
            if(i-1>-1 ){ if (b[i].equals(b[i-1])){ left=true;}}

            if(left==false && right==false){l_r=false; break;}
        }
         if(l_r==true){rta="YES";}
         if(l_r==false){rta="NO";}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to return "YES" if there are at least two equal objects next to each other, and "NO" otherwise?

Comment: It seems to me like your code, although verbose, is correct. How do you initialize the array "b" and which result is not what you are expecting?

Comment: Since you're progressing from one end, you should never have to check behind. If `b[i].equals(b[i+1])` is enough to return "YES".

Comment: Hi! Thnks for responding. The method expect that if there is at least one match next to the position X for every position, the result is YES. But i dont know why BABA (for example) result in YES. The array is from a string passed to array with .split("");

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED. There was a sort() changing the word. THANKS!!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your question is: Object at position X in an array of strings should at least match the object in either position (X-1) or position (X+1) i.e previous or next positions. It returns true if all the positions in the array satisfy this condition otherwise returns false.

```
int len = b.length;           
boolean l_r=true;
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            boolean left=false;
            boolean right=false;

            if(i+1<len ){if(b[i].equals(b[i+1])){ right=true;}}
            if(i-1>-1 ){if(b[i].equals(b[i-1])){ left=true;}}

            if(left==false && right==false){l_r=false; break;}
        }
        if(l_r==true)
            System.out.println("YES");
        if(l_r==false)
            System.out.println("NO");
```

Just cleaned up your code a bit, everything else(including logic) remains the same. This code returns the right answer.

Comment: `answer` is not defined. Did you mean `l_r`? This is also just a reformatted form of the OP's code.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I tried with another variable 'answer' in my system. Edited it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi! thnks for responding. The condition is like Kichoo said. The bool l_r is when the condition is accepted or not. THe problem can be the inizialization of the array??The array is from a string passed to array with .split("");

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED. There was a sort() changing the word. THANKS FOR THE HELP